# Retrieve name of property incl. class and namespace

Tags: c#

I added a resource file `LocalizedTexts.resx` to a project. The designer automatically added a class `MyNamespace.LocalizedTexts` to that project. Then I added a string resource `MyResourceName` to `LocalizedTexts`, and the designer created the static property `internal static string MyResourceName` in that class.

How can I get the full name of that property, i.e. `MyNamespace.LocalizedTexts.MyResourceName`, in a "compile-time" static way?

`nameof(LocalizedTexts.MyResourceName)` returns `MyResourceName` only, I could write `nameof(MyNamespace)+"."+nameof(LocalizedTexts)+"."+nameof(MyResourceName)`, but that looks like a WTF...

I need something compile time static because I'd like to use it with an `Attribute`, i.e.`[DescriptionResource("put that string here")]`.

Thanks for your hints.

Comment: Nope, there's nothing that would give that. (It's a reasonable request, but there's nothing in C# for it.)

Comment: While there's no built-in feature, would it be sufficient to pass `typeof(LocalizedTexts)` and `nameof(MyResourceName)` to the attribute? The attribute could then resolve the `Type` value to the fully-qualified name, and concatenate the property name. That seems a bit less awkward than stringing a bunch of `nameof` together.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks, that lead to a solution. I changed the `DescriptionResourceAttribute` to also include that `Type`, added it as first parameter of the attribute, and changed a few hundred places where it was used...

Comment: Consider posting an answer that describes (with code) the solution you wound up using, and self-accepting, so that your question is identified as having been resolved.